# Programmatically Open a MenuCommand in SettingsPane in Windows8 Metro Apps

Tags: windows-8, appsettings

I have a case in which i wish to open up a Pop Up associated with a menu command in the settings Pane programmatically on a Button Click in the Application . I do not wish to create a new settingsCommand rather get a Menu already present in the settings Pane.
Any help will be appreciated... Sorry if i am not much clear..

Thanks and Regards,
Graham